# Find expressions for the single sums $X$ with simple annuities

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

> Find expressions for the single sums $X$ equivalent to the set of seven payments of **Fig. 5-21** at times $(a)1,(b)5,(c)12$ and $(d)12$, assuming a rate $i$ per period.

**Solution:**

$(a)$ At $1$, $X$ is the discounted value of a deferred annuity with deferment $k=3$ periods.
$$X=Ra_{\bar{7}|i}(1+i)^{-3}$$

$(b)$ At $5$, $X$ is the discounted value of an annuity due,
$$X=Ra_{\bar{7}|i}(1+i)$$

$(c)$ At $8$, $X$ is the discounted value of an ordinary annuity of $4$ payments and the discounted value of an ordinary annuity of three payments,
$$X=Ra_{\bar{4}|i}+Ra_{\bar{3}|i}$$

$(d)$ At $12$, $X$ is the discounted value of an annuity due,
$$X=Ra_{\bar{7}|i}(1+i)$$

Where, $$a_{\bar{n}|i} \text{ is called a discount factor for }n \text{ payments, or the discounted value of \$1 per period}$$
$$a_{\bar{n}|i}=\frac{1-(1+i)^{-n}}{i}$$
$$R=\text{ periodic payment of the annuity}$$

[image]

---

Now, My question is how they get the annuity type? For $(a)$ Why the deferment periods are $3$, isn't should be $4?$ Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At time $t = 1$, the first payment of $R$ at $t = 5$ occurs $4$ periods in the future.  So if we can either write the present value as an annuity-immediate where the deferral period is $3$ years, or as an annuity-due where the deferral period is $4$ years:  $$\require{enclose} X = R v^3 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i} = R v^4 \ddot a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i}$$ where $v = 1/(1+i)$ is the periodic present value discount factor.  In both cases, the equation of value is $$X = Rv^4 + Rv^5 + \cdots + Rv^{10}.$$

Similarly, at $t = 5$, the present value corresponds to an annuity-due with no deferral, because the first payment occurs at the same time:  $$X = R + Rv + Rv^2 + \cdots + Rv^6 = R\ddot a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i}.$$

At time $t = 8$, the equation of value is $$X = R(1+i)^3 + R(1+i)^2 + R(1+i) + R + Rv + Rv^2 + Rv^3.$$  This can be written in multiple ways, such as the **accumulated value** of an annuity-immediate or annuity-due, plus the present value of an annuity-due or annuity-immediate.  Or you can accumulate or discount a $7$-period annuity. $$X = Rs_{\enclose{actuarial}{4}i} + Ra_{\enclose{actuarial}{3}i} = R\ddot s_{\enclose{actuarial}{3}i} + R\ddot a_{\enclose{actuarial}{4}i} = R(1+i)^4 a_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i} = Rv^3 s_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i} = \cdots$$

A similar principle applies at $t = 12$.  Or we can just write it as $$X = R \ddot s_{\enclose{actuarial}{7}i}.$$

Note that the expressions you wrote for parts (c) and (d) are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks(+1) for your response, @heropup. Your answer helps me to clear the concept. And Yes, there was a typo in my $(c)+(d)$ solution. Could you suggest to me a book where simple annuities, general annuities, and Amortization were discussed in a simple word/language?